# send a mail using unix command with attachment and subject line

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to send a mail with attachment and a subject line using unix's mail command but I get an error if I have both. If I only have a subject line it works, if I only have a attachment it works but not both. Anyone know how to do this?

```
data.out | mail -s "DATA" abc@company.com < text.out
```

So this results in "Ambiguous input redirect"

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you say `cat data | cat <other`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.shelldorado.com/articles/mailattachments.html) you can do what you want as:

```
(cat text.out; uuencode data.out data.out) | mail -s "DATA" abc@company.com
```

Answer (score 4):

You're asking to send input from the `data.out` command into the `mail` command, as well as asking it to read from the file `text.out`; which is, to say the least ambiguous as the shell cannot do both.

If you want to get both the text and data into the mail message, then the easiest way to accomplish this is to do something like:

```
(cat text.out; data.out) | mail -s "DATA" abc@company.com
```

now if `data.out` is a file rather than a command, then you can just do:

```
cat text.out data.out | mail -s "DATA" abc@company.com
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is available `mutt` works well for this as well as it directly supports attachments.  I've found the `mail` program on some systems does not properly perform MIME encoding even if the attachment is piped in after being passed through `uuencode`.

An example of using `mutt` is:

```
echo "body text" | mutt -a attachment.txt -s "subject text" -- recipient@domain.com
```

Comment: for some reason I could not attach files like mutt does it (7bit encoded) with mail or msmtp mail. mutt worked for me. Thanks. I would love to learn how to do it though.

If anyone wants to reuse variables in ~/.muttrc, check [this tutorial](http://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/tag/custom-variables/).